# Codeigniter cannot validate the variable

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

valueWhen I want to validate posted value in Codeigniter, I do it in the following way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name','required|xss_clean|strip_tags|trim|max_length[50]|alpha');
```

But I cannot understand how can I do the same validation for $name variable if it is grabbed from url like this:

```
$name = end($this->uri->segment_array());
```

I tried to do this and then validate in the same way

```
$this->form_validation->set_value('name', $name);
```

but validation did not pass. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically we refer to this particular validation library as **Form Validation** which works on form data.

There are other methods such as using route files (which is a perfect tool in CI) that you can take advantage of for URL checking.

Beside any already-developed tools (like [uri-validator](http://formvalidation.io/validators/uri/)), you can write your own validating functions.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to use  form validation to validate variables as well?

Comment: As I have already said up there, you need to make a simple googling. BTW http://vancelucas.com/blog/valitron-the-simple-validation-library-that-doesnt-suck/ is a good one!